# Does DejaVu has support for CJK (chinese, japanese, korean) glyphs?

Tags: fonts, truetype, cjk, opentype

I'm thinking about using DejaVu font to create a [Ruby-like][1] font for CJK scripts.

However I'm not sure, does DejaVu **provide/support CJK glyphs?** Otherwise is there another reusable free/open font you recommend?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The wiki [Plan page](http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/Plans#General_plan) talk about reusing others work :

> CJK - best would be to reuse others work

The status document about [language coverage](http://sourceforge.net/p/dejavu/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/dejavu-fonts/langcover.txt) indicate that's there is no glyph for CJK:

> ja     Japanese                                      (0/6537)           (0/6537)           (0/6537)
>   ko     Korean                                        (0/2443)           (0/2443)           (0/2443)
>   zh-cn  Chinese (simplified)                       0% (2/6765)        0% (2/6765)        0% (2/6765)
>   zh-hk  Chinese Hong Kong Supplementary Character Set      (0/2213)           (0/2213)           (0/2213)
>   zh-mo  Chinese in Macau                              (0/2213)           (0/2213)           (0/2213)
>   zh-sg  Chinese in Singapore                       0% (2/6765)        0% (2/6765)        0% (2/6765)
>   zh-tw  Chinese (traditional)                         (0/13063)          (0/13063)          (0/13063)

## Alternative

The [Droid font has support for CJK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Droid_fonts#Typefaces) and is under Apache License

Answer (score 2):

The answers I see advertising "Droid" fonts as supporting Asian languages are false. No, the "Droid" fonts do not support Asian languages. (Droid Regular only has 197 characters in it. Hanzi has about 5000!) And worse, many web sites sell these fonts at up to $89 per sub-version.

One free font family which *does* support the Asian languages is "Gnu FreeFont", available here:

http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/freefont/

Gnu FreeFont supports Russian (Cyrillic), Greek, Arabic, Hebrew, Armenian, Georgian, Indian scripts (Devanagari, Bengali, Gujarati, Tamil, Malayalam), Chinese scripts (traditional Hanzi, simplified Hanzi, Bopomopho), Japanese scripts (Kanji, Katakana, Hiragana), and many others.

And another free font which covers nearly every language on Earth is "Unifont", which can be downloaded from here (right-click, select "Save Link As", then right-click and select "Un-Block" after downloading):

http://unifoundry.com/pub/unifont-11.0.01/font-builds/unifont-11.0.01.ttf

Comment: Official Droid font states there is [support for CJK](http://www.droidfonts.com/droidfonts/about/): _Support for CJK is provided by the Droid Sans "fallback" font. This font contains over 43,000 glyphs and includes support for Simplified Chinese (GB2312)_

Answer (score 1):

DejaVu doesn't support but Google-droid font supports.
In RPM you can install like this:

```
# yum search google-droid
# yum install -y google-droid-*-fonts
```

Comment: could you provide a link to support this statement and give more info about what is supported ?